# KeyPress para cerrar un formulario

Tags: formularios, vba

Intento hacer que unos formularios se cierren al pulsar 'Esc', mediante

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii = 27 Then Unload Me
End Sub
```

Pero no funciona. Tampoco con `KeyDown` o `KeyUp`.

Por alguna razón la subrutina no se llega a ejecutar (si en lugar del `If...` pongo un `msgbox` éste tampoco aparece).

Estoy utilizando **VBA** en **Microsoft Word 2003**

Answer (score 2):

He encontrando en Internet una solución. Se trata de poner a `False` la propiedad `TabStop` de todos los controles del formulario.

Pero el precio es alto. Mi formulario tiene un par de campos de texto sobre los que necesito poder desplazarme con `Tab`, sin verme obligado a hacerlo con el puntero del ratón.

Lo pongo aquí por si alguien se encuentra en una situación parecida y esta solución le resulta de utilidad. En mi caso no me sirve: prefiero no poder cerrarlo con `Esc` a no poder usar `Tab` para desplazarme por sus `TextBox`.

Por tanto para mi caso la pregunta sigue abierta.

Answer (score 0):

Para cerrar los formularios, pulsando <kbd>Esc</kbd>, yo hago lo siguiente:

1. Instancio un `CommandButton` y lo ubico en un lugar que no sea visible en el formulario.
2. En la ventana propiedades, asigno el valor `false` a la propiedad `Cancel`.
3. En el evento clic del `CommandButton` ingreso el código: `Unload Me`.

Comment: Uf, olvidé que había una respuesta. Mañana lo miro. Gracias Víctor

Answer (score 0):

La solución de Víctor es muy creativa. Es buena idea usar un botón que no se vea por estar fuera del formulario como botón Cancel, pero hay un error en la solución:

Al botón hay que ponerle la propiedad Cancel a True, para que el botón capture la pulsación de la tecla Esc.

Hecho así, lo he probado y funciona de 10 :-)

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/407862)